# display the tweets from mongodb in localhost how i have do it

Tags: mongodb, twitter

In order to insert the tweets in mongodb i wrote the below code

```js
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Now i want to fetch the tweets from the mongodb and display to the browser. i am trying this since three day, can anyone help me .

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the code you have supplied?

Comment: i just said the logic of code just give me a idea to display in browser